# How can an app automatically deploy to a user's gh-pages?

Tags: git, heroku, github-pages

So I have an app hosted on Heroku which takes as input some JSON files and outputs a website contained in a downloadable folder. Now I am wondering what would be the way to automatically publish this output website to a user's Github pages(after taking the user's permission).

What I am understanding is that we have to first authenticate the user with the Github and then some use some API which GitHub provides to push the contents to the branch but I haven't been able to properly formulate a solution.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can ask for the user for a [PAT (Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/), that the user can revoke at any time), then you can use that to push directly your website to the GitHub Pages user's repo.

Depending on his/her GitHub page repo, you would simply push the content to the `master` branch (instead of `gh-pages` branch), [since August 2016](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing).

So you should not need any special API other than `git push`.